# En Colombia, ¿qué es una "pelada" o "peladita"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, colombia, bolivia

En la serie *Narcos* hoy estaban hablando de gente y de repente vino el momento de decidir a quién matar:

> Dale plomo a esa **peladita**

Estaban refiriéndose a una chica joven, de unos veinte años, por lo que entendí que es una forma de decir *joven*, *chica* o similar.

Sin embargo, recordé haber oído esta palabra entre colombianos para definir a gente más joven, algo así como *adolescentes*.

Por tanto, me pregunto: ¿para qué rangos de edad se usa el término? ¿es de uso solamente coloquial?

Sería muy interesante también saber su origen, pues la RAE se limita a decir:

> [**pelado<sup>1</sup>, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SMPEGoX)
>   Del part. de pelar.8. m. y f. coloq. Bol. y Col. Niño, muchacho.

Y [Bogotalogo](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94635822/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital) indica:

> 1. Jovencito.
>   2. Individuo falto de recursos pecuniarios.

¿Será que aplica a esa gente que a esa edad siempre tiene las rodillas peladas de heridas que se producen jugando?

Comment: Pelada o peladita en Colombia es un referente para decir tambien muchacha (una joven, menor 18 años).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Pelado, pelada, peladito, peladita** se refieren a una persona joven en general.

El origen se refiere a que la persona joven carece de vello púbico por lo tanto está "pelado".

A pesar de que el origen de **pelado** está asociado a la etapa previa a la adolescencia, se usa para referirse a personas de menos de 20 años aunque si la persona que usa la frase es muy mayor podría estarse refiriendo a una persona algo por encima de los 20.

El diminutivo **peladito** generalmente se usa para referirse a niños de menos de 10 o 12 años pero también puede usarse como apelativo cariñoso con alguien mayor a esa edad. (no es el caso del ejemplo en la pregunta).

> Hay que educar bien a los **pelados** para que no sigan el camino de los narcos.
>
> Esa **peladita** me cae bien.

Otra acepción es estar **sin dinero** p.ej:

> Pagué el arriendo y quedé *pelado*

En éste caso, *pelado* es sinónimo de peluqueado o calvo o **sin nada encima**, o sea, sin dinero.

Es frecuente que las personas jóvenes también vivan escasos de dinero porque aún no tienen un empleo, por lo que podrás escuchar algo como:

> Ese pelao anda pelao (la forma más frecuente de pronunciarlo es sin la d).

o su sinónimo: *"ese pelao anda sin cinco"*.

Answer (score 1):

El  [Diccionario de Americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/) traduce

**PELADA** como

> f. Ec:O. Mujer

y

**PELADITA** como

> I.  1.  m. y f. Mx. pelado, persona de bajo estrato social.
>
> II. 1.  m. y f. Ec. Muchacho, niño pequeño.
>          2. Bo:E. Criatura en el vientre de la madre. pop.