# ¿Por qué "chimba" es bueno en Colombia y malo en Argentina?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, colombia, hispanoamérica, argentina

Hace poco vi en algún sitio la palabra *chimba*. Esta palabra tiene muchas acepciones en el DRAE:

> [**chimba**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8mkVe0U)
>   Del quechua chimba 'de la otra banda'.
>   1. f. coloq. Hond. Arma de fuego de fabricación artesanal.
>
> [**chimbo<sup>2</sup>, ba**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8mu3Gkt%7C8mwKk0u)
>   De or. vasco.
>   1. adj. fest. bilbaíno (‖ natural de Bilbao). U. t. c. s.
>   2. m. P. Vasco. Nombre de varias especies de pájaros: alcaudón, colirrojo, curruca, etc.
>
> **chimbo<sup>4</sup>, ba**
>   1. adj. Dicho de una persona: De un pueblo amerindio que habitaba en la región central de los Andes ecuatorianos. U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a los chimbos.

Dejemos de lado *chimbo<sup>2</sup>* para centrarnos en su uso en Hispanoamérica. Por ello, añadamos lo que indica la web *asihablamos.com*:

> [**Significado de Chimba en Latinoamérica**](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Chimba.php)
>
> **en Argentina Argentina**
>   Grasa, villero, de clase social baja. (en sentido despectivo). Expresión que margina, excluye, estigmatiza ciertas personas con características sociales distintas.
>   Personas que les gusta escuchar cumbia villera, que se visten desprolijos.
>   *Callate chimba, sali chimba* (es: sali mugriento, grasa, etc)
>
> **en Colombia Colombia**
>   Puede significar dos cosas distintas dependiendo de la forma de decirlo (solo se puede distinguir al hablar) por ejm. "que comida tan chimba" puede ser que es muy buena (se puede usar bacana en lugar de chimba). O por el contrario que es pésima. Es tan extraña que incluso al hablar algunas veces toca preguntarle a la persona que quiere decir, si bueno o malo.
>
> (bueno:) *fui a ese restaurante nuevo, que comida tan chimba, tengo que regresar a comer ahi.*
>   (malo:) *que reloj tan chimbo, lo compré ayer y hoy ya no funciona.*

Además, en la web se refleja:

- Ecuador: tanto bueno como malo.
- Honduras: arma de fuego (ya definido por el DRAE).
- Perú: cabeza.
- Venezuela: algo malo, pésimo, aburrido.

Por ello, me pregunto: ¿cuál es su uso más extendido? ¿cómo puede haber evolucionado tanto para definir cosas opuestas incluso en el mismo país (Ecuador)?

Comment: Pues échale un vistazo al [diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=chimba) de ASALE que lo vas a flipar.

Comment: El problema de los significados opuestos es que esos diccionarios no diferencian bien entre el masculino y el femenino y eso es lo que hace la mayor diferencia.  Espero que mi respuesta ayude a aclarar el significado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me limitaré a dar la mitad de la respuesta que corresponde a Colombia. Para la Argentina ver la [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18512/por-qu%C3%A9-chimba-es-bueno-en-colombia-y-malo-en-argentina/18523#18523) de rsanchez.

La definición sencilla en Colombia es que Chimba/o se refiere al órgano sexual femenino/masculino
Ver entre otros:
 - El Bogotálogo o *Diccionario del español bogotano, por Andrés Ospina. Editado por el Instituto Distrital de Patrimonio Cultural* pag 58 [aquí](https://www.scribd.com/doc/94635822/Bogotalogo-Version-Digital) o [aquí](https://issuu.com/elblogotazo/docs/bogotalogo)).
 - [The Unique Paisa-English Dictionary pag 70](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=cgDRODrDR5UC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=una%20chimba&source=bl&ots=uiRNEA-SgN&sig=IupnBRMA8XeQuv9u_FscA9LePn4&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=una%20chimba&f=false)

Obviamente a partir de ahí aparecen varias acepciones y usos, todos vulgares, coloquiales, no muy elegantes y nada recomendados para situaciones formales.

**Usualmente** el femenino se usa para expresiones positivas y el masculino para expresiones negativas.

Algunos ejemplos:

## Femenino

1. Excelente: Es la palabra favorita de Juanes para expresar que algo es lo máximo:

   ¡Colombia es una *chimba* la hp!
   ver https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNfNvep9ZSk

   ¡Que *chimba*!, me gané el Grammy.
   ver https://youtu.be/paQRXvbH0OU?t=16s
2. Bonita/o:

   Esa [peladita](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18474/en-colombia-qu%C3%A9-es-una-pelada-o-peladita) es una *chimbita*. = Esa jovencita es muy bonita.

   ¡Qué *chimba* de carro! / ¡Qué carro tan *chimba*! = Ese automóvil es muy bonito.
3. Nunca:

   - Prestame 20 lucas (sin tilde) = ¿Me puedes prestar veinte mil pesos? = can you lend me COP$20000?
   - ¿Prestame? ¡*la chimba*! = ¿qué? ¡nunca! = what? No way!
4. Nada:

   - Los últimos 20 lucas que te presté nunca me los pagaste. Yo a vos no te presto *ni chimba*.
5. Por un pelo/de pura suerte:

   Uy, casi estrello el carro del cucho. Me salvé de *chimba*. = Estuve a punto de dañar el automóvil de mi padre pero evité el accidente por milímetros.

## Masculino

1. Falso:

   Ese reloj es *chimbo*. (ese reloj es falso) That watch is a fake/rip-off

   Ese cheque le salió *chimbo* = Ese cheque no tenía fondos y no lo pudo cobrar
2. Malo, aburrido, inútil:

   Que trabajo tan *chimbo* = Este trabajo que estoy haciendo no tiene sentido.

   El almuerzo estuvo *rechimbo*. = El almuerzo estuvo muy pero muy mal.

   El técnico no supo qué jugadores llamar a la selección. ¡¡*Rechimbo* ese técnico!!

## Derivados.

Chimbiar:
  1. Molestar, irritar.
  2: Perder el tiempo en tareas inútiles o improductivas.

Chimbada:
   1. Cosa o situación sin valor o sin importancia.
   2. Expresión de frustración. *¡Qué chimbada! Perdí el examen de matemáticas.*

[(otros ejemplos)](https://books.google.com.co/books?id=cgDRODrDR5UC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=una%20chimba&source=bl&ots=uiRNEA-SgN&sig=IupnBRMA8XeQuv9u_FscA9LePn4&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=una%20chimba&f=false)

Comment: Qué curioso lo de _Usualmente el femenino se usa para expresiones positivas y el masculino para expresiones negativas_. En España todo lo relacionado con _cojones_ se valora como positivo (cojonudo, tener cojones), mientras que lo relacionado con _coño_ se valora como negativo (ser un coñazo, estar de coña).

Comment: _Me salvé de chimba_ no la he escuchado, pero sí he escuchado: _Me salvé de **chiripa**_.

Comment: En Cali, Colombia se puede usar "chimbo" para referirse al órgano sexual masculino, además de las expresiones negativas. Identificarlo sería parte del contexto.

Answer (score 6):

Jamás había escuchado *chimba* en Buenos Aires. Al parecer se empezó a usar en forma reciente con sentido despectivo solamente en una provincia de Argentina, Mendoza. Y es por referencia a un departamento de la provincia vecina, San Juan, según dice [este artículo](http://www.tiempodesanjuan.com/sanjuan/2015/11/2/mendoza-chimbas-mala-palabra-109923.html):

> Chimbas es uno de los departamentos más poblados de San Juan. Los primeros en asentarse en la comuna fueron inmigrantes chilenos y criollos desempleados que compraron tierras allí porque se vendían muy baratas debido a su escasa fertilidad. Como las tierras no eran aptas para el desarrollo agrícola fueron conceptuadas desde un principio peyorativamente, siendo ocupadas por sectores sociales de bajo nivel económico.

Sobre *chimba* en Colombia y alrededores en [*este audio*](http://www.lafm.com.co/audios/bogota/05-07-12/significado-de-chimba-y-cacorr-115281) explican que quería decir originalmente "la otra orilla del río", que de allí pasó a denominar "el órgano genital femenino", y de allí puede pasar a significar algo malo o bueno según la carga emocional que se le quiera dar.

Comment: Es una noticia para mí que exista esta palabra en Argentina (soy de Rosario). Qué desagradable es la facilidad con que aparecen términos despectivos…

Comment: Yo tampoco conocía esta palabra. Soy de Buenos Aires.

Answer (score 2):

En Colombia, *chimba* puede tener significados buenos y malos, por ejemplo:

> - Qué chimbada eso.
>   <sub>Qué feo eso, qué malo.</sub>
>
> -Qué chimba de partido.
>   <sub>Qué bueno fue el partido.</sub>

Depende del asunto con el que trates la palabra, aunque te recomiendo no usarla, suele ser una expresión muy populista.

Comment: Gracias Daniel por tu apunte. Lo de _suele ser una expresión muy populista_ no acabo de entenderlo, ¿a qué te refieres exactamente?

Comment: Populista , hago referencia a que es una expresión común usada en la calle , pero que no se vera bien en un entorno formal como una reunion , podrías usar: - que chevere en una reunion es un poquito mas elegante.

Comment: Ah vale lo que diríamos coloquial.

Comment: No es coloquial , como en colombia dirían gamin o indecente en algunos casos

Answer (score 2):

En Colombia, *chimba* es un termino **callejero**, mayoritariamente usada por ñeros (nacos === México).

*Chimba* define algo como "buenísimo", grande, amplio, fantástico, impresionante, etc. Define como algo **apreciable**. Aunque claro, añadiendo sarcasmo es todo lo contrario:

> *No pues, tan chimba, ¿no?*.

**Es un término muy, pero muy diferente de "chimbo"**.

Esta última define como algo de muy mala calidad, o una porquería. Sucede que en otros paises se confunde "chimbo" con "chimba" solo porque *no hay diferencia ampliamente notoria en la palabra*.

Dependiendo del contexto en el que se use, porque *"qué chimba"* puede ser o **no** sarcástico. Es fácilmente notable cuando **estás hablando personalmente**.

Puedo decir:

> *uff, ¡qué chimba este celular!*.

Con ello puedo indicar que **me gusta** el celular, o que **simplemente estoy burlándome del mismo**.

- El tono de voz define el sarcasmo.

Normalmente esta terminología está empezando a ser rechazada por la sociedad, en especial estratos igual o mayores a 3, poca gente de estratos 1 y 2 nota esto algo muy grosero e irrespetuoso. (Nota: los estratos en Colombia se refieren a la estratificación socioeconómica, siendo el 1 el más bajo y 6 el más alto).

Esta clase de palabras tienen muchísimo uso entre amigos, o conocidos muy importantes, es algo muy normal. Teniendo en cuenta el anterior párrafo.

Algunos artistas como **Juanes** siempre destacan el lenguaje de Colombia y las variedades del mismo. Por estilo de demostrar cómo se habla en Colombia es aceptable, de lo contrario podría no ser así. Como algunos dicen, habla y con ello defines quién eres.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, Máxima, gracias por tu tiempo. Me permití añadir una pequeña explicación de qué son los estratos en Colombia para quien no lo conozca.

Comment: Una cosa, @fedorqui... "Ésta, éste, éstos, éstas" está correctamente escrito, solo que la RAE asegura que **no es obligatorio** agregar la tílde, sin embargo la agrego para mejor lectura.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz no, desde hace unos (pocos) años ya no. Como se lee en [¿Cuándo se debe acentuar el pronombre “este”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18540/1674): _"los casos reales en los que se produce una ambigüedad que el contexto comunicativo no es capaz de despejar son raros y rebuscados, y siempre pueden evitarse por otros medios", así que en la práctica puedes escribirlo siempre sin tilde directamente._

Comment: Claro, aunque de igual modo no está mal.

Comment: Máxima: no, fíjate que tu uso incluso con la regla antigua era incorrecta. Decías _Ésta última define como algo de muy mala calidad_. En este caso _este_ es un determinante demostrativo, cuando la tilde se ponía en los pronombres (ejemplo: _Ayer hablé con Juan. Éste me comentó que..._). Más info en [El adverbio solo y los pronombres demostrativos, sin tilde](http://www.rae.es/consultas/el-adverbio-solo-y-los-pronombres-demostrativos-sin-tilde)